# TestNG - How to store and retrieve groups as an object

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm curious if there is an approach that allows me to simply store the list of groups in a separate base class and call when needed?

For example:

```
@Test(groups = {"IT", "IE", "GG", "JE", "IM", "GF", "GP", "MQ", "BL", "MF", "NC", "WF", "BE", "DK", "FI", "IS", "LU", "SE", "PT"})
```

I'd like to wrap this list as an object to simply call so the test looks clean

Desired outcome:

```
@Test(groups = "proxyRegions")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Annotation value cannot be evaluated in runtime. As the alternative you can build a [group `proxyRegions` of groups](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#groups-of-groups) you have mentioned hence your test would run for all of them.